# How to execute ALL function in spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I just want to know how to execute the following MySQL query in spark SQL.

```
SELECT first_name,last_name, job_id, salary 
  FROM employees 
 WHERE salary > 
   ALL (SELECT salary FROM employees WHERE job_id = 'SH_CLERK') 
 ORDER BY salary
```

specially `ALL()` function.

Answer (score 0):

ALL is not available with SPARK SQL currently. Neither is it used by many with SQL and it can be converted to other approaches.

In this case a MAX would achieve the same result as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
   ("John", "sh_clerk", 20000), ("Peter", "sh_clerk", 60000), ("Sally", "manager", 50000),
   ("Cabe", "programmer", 100000), ("Bob", "accountant", 65000)
)).toDF("first_name", "job_type", "salary")

df.createOrReplaceTempView("employees")


val res = spark.sql(""" SELECT first_name, job_type, salary 
  FROM employees 
 WHERE salary > 
   (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employees WHERE job_type = 'sh_clerk') 
 ORDER BY salary""") 

res.show(false)
```

returning:

```
+----------+----------+------+
|first_name|job_type  |salary|
+----------+----------+------+
|Bob       |accountant|65000 |
|Cabe      |programmer|100000|
+----------+----------+------+
```